# What does this.$something = this.$('something') mean?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I've just started going through [backbone fundamentals](http://addyosmani.github.com/backbone-fundamentals/) and don't quite understand what's going on here:

```
this.$input = this.$('#new-todo');
```

Could someone give me an overview / breakdown of what this actually does?

From what my limited understanding tells me, `this.$('#new-todo')` is a typical jquery selector, that finds the `#new-todo` (an input) and gives it to `this.$input`, which (according to [this](http://addyosmani.github.com/backbone-fundamentals/#what-is-el)) is a shorthand of sort for $(this + 'input'), but here's where I loose it - why is that actually there? Is it really just assigning the `#new-todo` from the DOM to $(this + 'input')? If so, wouldn't be better just to use the this.$('something') DOM selector instead of what's in the this.$input?

Comment: I think it's just retrieving an input and storing it in a `$input` property on the context (this). I don't use backbone though, so there might be more going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code example is caching the jQuery element.

When you use the jQuery constructor, you are querying the DOM; finding all elements that match. Depending on the selector you use, this could potentially be a very expensive operation.

If you plan to use a jQuery object multiple times, it is better to only query the DOM once.

Here is an example:

```
var foo = $('.someClass');
foo.css("background-color", "yellow");
console.log(foo.length + " items updated");
```

Even though the code above used `foo` multiple times, the DOM was only queried once.

Wouldn't it be nice if your code made the fact that `foo` is a jQuery object a little more obvious?

```
// a lot of developers like to prepend a $ to variable names
var $foo = $('.someClass');
```

Comment: Yup this is the same conclusion I got to after a bit of head scratching. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`Backbone.$` delegates to jQuery (or Zepto).

In this case `this.$` will delegate to jQuery and return an element with id `new-todo`

`this.$input` is a naming convention to indicate that `$input` is a jQuery object.

The  this object refers to a Backbone instance and not a DOM context.

```
this.$ == jQuery
```

`this.$input` is just an attribute.

`this.$input = this.$("#new-todo");` can be rewritten as:

`this.input = jQuery("#new-todo");` or

```
this.input = $("#new-todo");
```

`$input` is just an arbitrary named property, just like variables can be named as `$foo`, `$bar` etc.

Answer (score 0):

It's not doing `$(this + 'input')` that I know of because that would probably be invalid unless `this` is a string.  I don't know Backbone, but it seems that `this.$` is jQuery, so `this.$("#new-todo")` in Backbone is the same as `jQuery('#new-todo')`, which just selects that element.  Storing it in a member named `$input` allows you to only call the jQuery selector function once, and it also allows you to reference `this.$input` in other methods without having to know the original selector.

Answer (score 0):

`this.$input` will be just an attribute to the `object` which `this` is pointing to.

And `this.$('#new-todo')` will find and return the matching element from the current view (element pointed by `el` for the view).

When we do `this.$`, according to the [docs](http://backbonejs.org/#View-dollar), the queries to get the element specified by the selector are scoped within the view's element (say el). [Here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1) is what scope means in `jQuery`, referred by `context` there.

Hence `this.$('#new-todo')` isn't same as `jQuery('#new-todo')`.